# where does WinRAR extract files to by default in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, extract, winrar

where does WinRAR extract files to by default in Windows 7?

Because I need to locate an .ISO I just extracted...

Comment: Use the search box?

Comment: I wish people would pay attention when using software, if you did you would know where the file is. its a PICNIC error for sure, "Problem In Chair Not In Computer", if you don't start accepting answers your help here is going to be limited.

Answer (score 1):

usually to the directory of the rar file, folder name should be the same as the rar.

Comment: That is true. If you used your browser's "Open" button in a file, maybe you should look in your temporary internet files folder.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7, 8 and 10, it extracts the files to `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp`

Edit: If you run a file from inside the archive, the files will be extracted in the temp folder as mentioned earlier. If you use Extract or Extract without confirmation it will be in the same directory where your archive is.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's the temporary directory, OP is looking for the final directory not the temporary one.

Comment: Thanx for pointing out unless other people just downvoting. Well in that case its the same directory where your archive is located. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Open WinRAR > Options > Settings > Compression Tab

If **Default folder for extracted files** is blank and **Append archive name to path** then it extracted in a new folder of same folder the file was in. The new folder should be exact name of the source file.

#### WinRAR Help:

> **Default folder for extracted files**
> You may enter here a name of the folder, which will be used as a base to construct the destination folder in Extract without confirmation and Extract files to the specified folder commands. WinRAR builds the destination path in these extraction commands merging the default folder and an archive name. It may be convenient to enter Desktop path here, so you will immediately see unpacked data on your Desktop.
>
> **Append archive name to path**
> It controls if archive name is appended to the default folder name when constructing the destination path.